# Excel output based on date

Tags: excel

I'm trying to do a real estate pro forma with yearly rents.  The total rent is reported on a yearly basis and that starts when the property is purchased.  If I buy a property in May, year 1 will be May 2014 to April 2015.

Leases can be signed at any time and will include an increase after each 12-month period.  If I sign a lease in July 2014 then the rent will increase in July 2015.

I want to be able to calculate the yearly rent based on the reporting period and including any rent increases throughout the year.  For the above example, the property is purchased in May 2014 so there will be $0 rent for May and June, then $xxx rent for July through December. I want to be able to make a table with dates and rents and have a formula calculate a yearly rent total taking into account that X number of months will be at $x and Y number of months will be at $y.

I have the years in rows, for example Year 1, Year 2, Year 3, etc.  Under each year I have exact dates like 5/1/2014, 5/1/2015, etc.  I have a table of rents, for example 7/1/14 $500, 7/1/15 $500, etc.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: We **help** with homework; but we don't **do** homework.

Comment: What I've done so far is to have a cell with the number of months next to the monthly rate.  So for Year 1 I have 9 and 3, meaning the rate is constant for 9 months then changes for the last 3.  It multiplies 9 time $x and 3 times $y and then adds the total.  It works but I'm guessing there must be a better way with a formula.

Comment: This is the formula I got to work, in a way:  =(MONTH(A11-F10)*C10)+(13-MONTH(A11))*C11.  It helps as long as there is no vacancy.

Answer (score 0):

Per OP:

> This is the formula I got to work, in a way:
>
> ```
> =(MONTH(A11-F10)*C10)+(13-MONTH(A11))*C11
> ```
>
> It helps as long as there is no vacancy.